# How can I create a GPO script per user for Windows 7 (local machine/non domain client)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy, userscripts

I would like to create a logon script for a particular user on my Windows 7 PC.

I tried changing the setting in `gpedit.msc` but this affects all users including admin users.

Where can I change the GPO settings per user and/or how do I go about starting a script for this logon?

The logon script *must* change/alter the Group Policy settings to disable the features below:

### Script Requirements

- Disable ability to modify desktop files/links
- Hide Hard Disk from Explorer, disable Access via Explorer.exe GP Setting ->(`Admin Templates\Windows Components\Windows Explorer\Prevent Access to Drives from My Computer`)

### Scenario

- The PC is NOT part of a domain.
- The user I want to create a logon script for is a standard user and not administrator.
- The script should not affect the administrator logons.

When the user logs off, the script should not affect any other user.

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Can you edit your answer to include your script? Is there a particular section of your script that you are having trouble with?

Comment: I havnt created a script as yet. I just edited the gpedit.msc setting directly in the UI which affected all users. I would like to know how to create a script for this and where do I run it from.